# Python can't import numpy when starting .py file. Otherwise it works (Win10)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, import

I use Win10 and Python3.10.
My problem is that I can't execute the .py file with `import numpy` in it. I'm sure that numpy is installed - if I start Python using the command line in Windows and input some simple code directly

```
import numpy as np
my_first_array = np.array([1, 2, 3,4,5])
my_first_array
```

it works.
But if I input exactly the same code within the `.py` file and try it execute with by `numpy_test.py` I get a traceback error like below:

```
  File "C:\Users\pawel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\platform.py", line 831, in uname
    system, node, release, version, machine = infos = os.uname()
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'uname'. Did you mean: 'name'?
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\TESTY\PY4E\numpy_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\pawel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 144, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\pawel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 100, in <module>
    from . import _add_newdocs_scalars
  File "C:\Users\pawel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_add_newdocs_scalars.py", line 87, in <module>
    add_newdoc_for_scalar_type('byte', [],
  File "C:\Users\pawel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_add_newdocs_scalars.py", line 62, in add_newdoc_for_scalar_type
    alias_doc += ''.join(":Alias on this platform ({} {}): `numpy.{}`: {}.\n    ".format(platform.system(), platform.machine(), alias, doc)
  File "C:\Users\pawel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_add_newdocs_scalars.py", line 62, in <genexpr>
    alias_doc += ''.join(":Alias on this platform ({} {}): `numpy.{}`: {}.\n    ".format(platform.system(), platform.machine(), alias, doc)
  File "C:\Users\pawel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\platform.py", line 908, in system
    return uname().system
  File "C:\Users\pawel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\platform.py", line 834, in uname
    node = _node()
  File "C:\Users\pawel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\platform.py", line 582, in _node
    return socket.gethostname()
AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'gethostname'*
```

I have already reinstalled Python several times and spent several hours looking for solutions online. Could someone please give me a comprehensible solution to this issue?

Comment: have you installed numpy? It is not part of the python standard library like say os is. If you have pip installed you can install numpy by running 'pip install numpy' in your terminal. Have a look here https://numpy.org/install/

Comment: I'm sure Numpy is installed and I'm sure I have windows installer of Python. I managed to somehow solve the problem by moving the .py file which has "import numpy" element directly to Python directory. However it needs to be directly in my Python directory; putting it in some other subdirectories gieves the same traceback.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed in your PC?

Comment: Ensure that you have only one python version and no other software or platforms are embedding python into windows, often times it is the issue. Clean all installed python, WSL python, other python versions and your problem will be solved.